# regular point grid spacing QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, distance

I want to make simple regular point grid for a polygon but of known distance in meters between points, in QGIS using regular points research tool. How do I input my own distance? The spacing value '0.0001' is not clear what metric that is

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  For example what software are you using, what have you tried so far, and what is your input data?

Comment: @JimT I think it's a QGIS question.

Comment: Apologies yes QGIS

Comment: @JimT I have 3 polygons which are representing areas for a survey. I want to place points in a grid each at i.e. 6km apart within the polygon. How do I use the tool to input 6km?

Comment: A tenth millimeter grid over an object measured in meters is going to be ***HUGE***, with **100 million** points per square meter. Please [edit] the question to specify the software you are using the objects you are sampling.

Comment: @Vince I don't believe the 0.0001 is a mm. Its not clear anywhere what metric is being used by the program. I'm using UTM but that seems to make no difference so presumably its not in meters of any kind

Comment: Please **edit the question** to contain changes requested in comments. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information. See the [tour] for a better idea how our Q&A site works.

Comment: @rae, that number is only a default value which has the units of measurement of your CRS. It makes sense for CRS using degrees (so, it would be `0,0001` degrees of lat/lon) but, in your situation, they are assumed as meters (so, it becomes `0.0001` m). In your case, you need to insert `6000` as input value.

Answer (score 7):

The **Regular points** tool uses `0.0001` by default and this is a value which has the units of measurement of your CRS. It makes sense for CRS using degrees (so, it would be `0,0001` degrees of lat/lon), but not for those using meters or feet as units.

Referring to your comments, it seems that you are working with a Projected Coordinate System and, if you need to generate a new point every 6 km, you should insert `6000` as input value.

This explanation is for the `Point spacing/count` parameter, but it also applies to the `Initial inset from corner (LH side)` one.